# CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.1'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing

I've recently bought a new Macbook Air, installed all my software including Xcode, I've gone to work on my project and I keep getting the Code Signing Error!

I've download my Certs/Profiles from the iOS Dev page still nothing!

I've checked my Keychain and can't see anything wrong?

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that your computer has the private keys associated with the certificates? Simply downloading the certificates isn't going to work. If you can't get the private keys back, then you should revoke and recreate your certificates. Then update the provisioning profiles.

Comment: Just out of interest if I revoke my certs while I have an app pending with Apple will there be a problem?

Comment: Any apps already signed and submitted will be fine. There shouldn't be a problem.